# PHP - Split String html elements

Tags: php, html

I have a string variable that contains 3 trs:

```
$string = '<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>';
```

I try to split the string to get 3 `<tr>...</tr>` Tags.

I have tried :

```
$match = preg_split('[(<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>)]', $string , NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but I don't get good results.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want the content between the two tags only? or the <tr> tags included? if you are happy with having entire `<tr>..</tr>` as stated in your question then all you have to do is filter out empty items.

Comment: Thanks Ali, it's already fixed by the FastTurtle's response.

Comment: Cheers, I've already up-voted his approach since it isn't rely on regular expression which makes it faster than my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend using regex to parse your HTML, but if you want to anyways, here is the correct way of doing it:

```
 $regexPattern = "/<tr>(.*?)<\\/tr>/"; 
 $string = "<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>"; 

 preg_match_all($regexPattern , $string , $matches);
```

As requested, here is the regex to include the tags:

```
 $regexPattern = "/(<tr>.*?<\\/tr>)/";
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks; `$regexPattern = "/<tr>.*?<\\/tr>/"; ` works better

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$string = '<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>';
$result = array_filter(explode('</tr>', str_replace('<tr>','',$string)));
print_r($result);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I like this solution ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I have now discovered that this code eliminates the `<tr>` tags. How can I edit it to let this ones ?

Comment: See my answer, it should be the accepted one and was posted earlier then this one.. ;) My answer can output with or without the tags.

Comment: @Boratzan: Ok, I have edited your post, like this: `$regexPattern = "/<tr>.*?<\\/tr>/"; ` and I get an array inside another one: 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Total 1 779,00
            [1] =>  Total 2 867,25
            [2] =>  Total 3 939,00
        )

)`
Can I also get only one array from this result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the three trs

```
preg_match_all('/<tr[^>]*>.*?<\/tr>/', $string , $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr>"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "<tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr>"
    [2]=>
    string(42) "<tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is nice, just filter empty results out using PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method

i.e.

```
<?php
$string = '<tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr><tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr><tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>';
$match = array_filter(preg_split('[(<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>)]', $string , -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));

print_r($match);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [1] => <tr><td> Total 1 </td><td>779,00</td></tr>
    [3] => <tr><td> Total 2 </td><td>867,25</td></tr>
    [5] => <tr><td> Total 3 </td><td>939,00</td></tr>
)
```